# Haskell's type associative chain is puzzling

Tags: haskell, types

I'm playing with some Haskell code. I've defined two functions:

```
count :: [a] -> Int
count []     = 0
count (x:xs) = 1 + (count xs)

-- 03. Write a function that computes the mean of a list, i.e., the sum of all 
-- elements in the list divided by its length. (You may need to use the 
-- fromIntegralfunction to convert the length of the list from an integer 
-- into a floating-point number.)

-- I've guessed this type definition, but it's incorrect:
-- listMean :: [a] -> Double
-- The following is the same inferred by hgci
listMean :: (Fractional a) => [a] -> a
listMean lst = (foldl1 (+) lst)/(fromIntegral (count lst))
```

Why [a] -> Double is not correct? It seems that I give lst that is a generic list of some type a and listMean returns a Double. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks,
Alfredo

Answer (score 20, accepted):

First of all, `listMean :: [a] -> Double` says that `listMean` is a function taking a list of any type `a` to a single `Double` value.

But you rely on being able to apply `(+)` to the elements of the list (`foldl1 (+)`), which requires that the type `a` be an instance of `Num`, which means you have at least:

```
listMean :: (Num a) => [a] -> b
```

You also apply `(/)` to the value of type `a` that results from the `foldl1` operation. To do so, `a` must not only be an instance of `Num`, but of `Fractional`. Applying this requirement to the type `a` gives the type signature:

```
listMean :: (Fractional a) => [a] -> b
```

Now, what of `b`? Well, the signature for `(/)` is `(/) :: (Fractional a) => a -> a -> a`. So, the result of `listMean` must also be an instance of `Fractional`. Further, it must be the same instance of `Fractional` as that contained in the list: type `b` is thus, in fact, type `a`, and `listMean`'s most general signature is:

```
listMean :: (Fractional a) => [a] -> a
```

This is exactly what the compiler inferred. If you want to specialize this for `Double`, you would have to replace *both* occurrences of `a` with `Double`:

```
listMean :: [Double] -> Double
```

This is because you have no operator in there that will coerce any instance of `Fractional` into a `Double`, so both input and output to `(/)` must be of type `Double`.